# Why are my images compressed?

Tags: android, drawable

I'm using layout xml file for the UI. But the images are compressed and the qualities have lost in some level.

My code is like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="480px"
    android:layout_height="717px"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:layout_y="45px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/e4" />
```

The drawable is actually `480x717`.

What's the problem here? Is it due to the fitXY?

Comment: are you're sure that your screen is at least 480x762?

Comment: yes, and after I removed the fitXY, the problem still exists

Comment: what phone are are you using? and what happens if you just set wrap_content as width and height?

Comment: tried wrap_content, but it's still the same..

Comment: Is this related to the Android-2.1-downgrade-image-quality issue?

Comment: Which phone and Android version are you using?

Comment: I've tried emulator and N1, both have this problem. I'm using Android 2.1

Comment: and this imageview is your root view? or are there any more view elements displayed at the same time?

Comment: no, it's not the root view. has a AbsoluteLayout parent, which simply has layout_width and layout_height set to fill_parent

Comment: BTW. the image used here is 24bit color

Comment: what is the output if you trie to read the screen resolution?

 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 System.out.println(metrics.widthPixels);

Comment: 没问题, 的确是480: 05-12 21:37:57.250 D/SplashActivity( 1116): width: 480

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is.

You say you want some dimensions, but then you say you want to scale it.

So it scales it.

Comment: I removed the fitXY, but it still lost some qualities. Is there other setting in Android/ImageView could make the image to be shown lose-less?

Comment: Try using center as scaleType. Check following link for different scaletypes available :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html